# How to use For loop to the below data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I have 15 cells, as shown below:

[image]

I would like to plot their data. As shown below, I drew the data for the first two cells.

```
% First case
figure
A = berMap(1,1);
% caculate the coverage area
isSmaller = cellfun( @(X) X < 0.0038, A(:), 'UniformOutput', false);
numSmaller = sum(sum(isSmaller{:} == 1)); 
% Draw BerMap
Coverage_area = (numSmaller/(41*41))*400;    %Important
surf(X_r,Y_r,A{1,1})
colorbar
view(0,90)
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('BER');
axis([-L/2 L/2 -W/2 W/2 min(min(A{1,1})) max(max(A{1,1}))]);
grid on;
hold on;
% Plotting the FEC
Amat = cell2mat(berMap(1,1));
Amat(Amat > 0.0038) = 0;
Amatrix = Amat;
Amatrix(Amat == 0) = nan;
hSurface = surf(X_r,Y_r,Amatrix);
set(hSurface, 'EdgeColor',[1 1 1],'FaceColor',[1 1 1]);
view(0,90)


%Second Case
figure
B = berMap(2,1);
% caculate the coverage area
isSmaller1 = cellfun( @(X) X < 0.0038, B(:), 'UniformOutput', false);
numSmaller1 = sum(sum(isSmaller1{:} == 1)); 
% Draw BerMap
Coverage_area1 = (numSmaller1/(41*41))*400;    %Importrant
surf(X_r,Y_r,B{1,1})
colorbar
view(0,90)
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('BER');
axis([-L/2 L/2 -W/2 W/2 min(min(B{1,1})) max(max(B{1,1}))]);
grid on;
hold on;
% Plotting the FEC
Amat1 = cell2mat(berMap(2,1));
Amat1(Amat1 > 0.0038) = 0;
Amatrix1 = Amat1;
Amatrix1(Amat1 == 0) = nan;
hSurface1 = surf(X_r,Y_r,Amatrix1);
set(hSurface1, 'EdgeColor',[1 1 1],'FaceColor',[1 1 1]);
view(0,90)
```

I would like to use a **for loop** in order to draw them without writing the above codes for 15 times.
Any assistance, please?

Comment: Assuming the code that plots the values is correct, you can include your code in the following loop `for i=1:numel(berMap),< your code>,end`. At each iteration, `berMap{i,1}` contains the data of the i-th element of the cellarray

Answer (score 0):

```
for bb=1:size(berMap,1) %bb is the index that loops through
figure
A = berMap(bb,1); %it is added here 
% caculate the coverage area
isSmaller = cellfun( @(X) X < 0.0038, A(:), 'UniformOutput', false);
numSmaller = sum(sum(isSmaller{:} == 1)); 
% Draw BerMap
Coverage_area = (numSmaller/(41*41))*400;    %Important
surf(X_r,Y_r,A{1,1})
colorbar
view(0,90)
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('BER');
axis([-L/2 L/2 -W/2 W/2 min(min(A{1,1})) max(max(A{1,1}))]);
grid on;
hold on;
% Plotting the FEC
Amat = cell2mat(berMap(bb,1)); %and here
Amat(Amat > 0.0038) = 0;
Amatrix = Amat;
Amatrix(Amat == 0) = nan;
hSurface = surf(X_r,Y_r,Amatrix);
set(hSurface, 'EdgeColor',[1 1 1],'FaceColor',[1 1 1]);
view(0,90)
hold off %remember to hold off
end
```

assuming the code you posted is correct and does what you want.
Note that you will have 15 figures popping all over the place. A wiser solution would be to use subplots/tiled charts and plot everything on one figure.

```
tiledlayout(size(berMap,1),1)
for bb=1:size(berMap,1) %bb is the index that loops through
nexttile
A = berMap(bb,1); %it is added here 
% caculate the coverage area
isSmaller = cellfun( @(X) X < 0.0038, A(:), 'UniformOutput', false);
numSmaller = sum(sum(isSmaller{:} == 1)); 
% Draw BerMap
Coverage_area = (numSmaller/(41*41))*400;    %Important
surf(X_r,Y_r,A{1,1})
colorbar
view(0,90)
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('BER');
axis([-L/2 L/2 -W/2 W/2 min(min(A{1,1})) max(max(A{1,1}))]);
grid on;
hold on;
% Plotting the FEC
Amat = cell2mat(berMap(bb,1)); %and here
Amat(Amat > 0.0038) = 0;
Amatrix = Amat;
Amatrix(Amat == 0) = nan;
hSurface = surf(X_r,Y_r,Amatrix);
set(hSurface, 'EdgeColor',[1 1 1],'FaceColor',[1 1 1]);
view(0,90)
hold off %remember to hold off
end
```